# Use of tick() after nested promise doesn't cause waiting for promises to finish (Karma/Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I need to make a test spec in Angular that checks that base64 string is converted into Blob object. Process of conversion involves nested promises:

```
fetch(testImage1).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {});
```

I test this process using this spec:

```
it( 'should update an image fakeAsync', fakeAsync( () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let imgBlob = null;
    // testImage1 = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//AwO/AwHVYZ/z5......'
    fetch(testImage1).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
        imgBlob = blob;
        expect(imgBlob).toBeTruthy(); //OK
    });
    tick();
    expect(imgBlob).toBeTruthy(); //test fails
} ));
```

As code demonstrates, spec is ran in fakeAsync block and tick() method is called after asynchronous code call. imgBlob should be set after tick() blocking function releases the flow of the program. But program flow is not stopped instead, second expectation is checked before asynchronous calls are finished. It leads to failing spec.

Angular CLI 6.2.6, Karma 3.1.1, Jasmine 2.8.0

As a workaround, this works:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(testImage1).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
            resolve(blob);
        });

    });
    imgBlob = await promise;
```

Comment: Are you mocking/spying the call to `fetch()`, or more specifically any underlying asynchronous service calls?  If so, please show that code.  If not then that may be your issue - fakeAsync won't work if there is real asynchronous code trying to fetch data from a real backend API for example.

Comment: As far as I understand, fetch() is not supposed to make requests to backend in this case. It should simply convert base64 to blob object.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, @dmcgrandle is correct that `fakeAsync` relies on monkey-patching asynchronous built-in methods (or rather, it relies on Zone.js patching them), and it explicitly does not support network requests.  At least, all of the documentation says that you cannot use XHR, and while I'm pretty surprised to find that it doesn't *explicitly* say that you can't use `fetch` either, it seems like a pretty safe bet.  It also isn't too surprising that they don't make an exception that allows `fetch` against a `data:` URL to be treated differently. Even if it doesn't actually trigger network activity, it still runs asynchronously using Promises.

Second, I'm not sure what your real code looks like, but the test as you've written it is basically checking that basic browser functionality (or your polyfill for it?) works correctly.  If you actually just need to make a Blob out of some static data, there are simpler methods for doing that without invoking `fetch`.